# Can I use a Custom Meta Value inside of 'get_the_terms'?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, page-template, terms

I have a custom Page Template, and this is the code that I am trying to manipulate to change depending on a custom meta value that I write for specific Pages.

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->id, 'custom-taxonomy' );
```

On the Page CPT, I have a custom meta field "Taxonomy Name", and the custom meta value is "Custom Taxonomy"

What I am trying to do with the code above is:

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->id, get_post_meta($post->ID,'metafield-taxonomy-name',TRUE) );
```

Obviously (through actually trying it ;)), that snippet doesn't work since the meta value is not passing through in quotes.

Is there a way I can achieve this, so that 'get_the_terms' can be changed dynamically depending on the meta value that I give it?

Thanks!

Roc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemed have found a solution via customizing a code snippet from here:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_the_terms-using-array-of-taxonomies

```
$taxonomy = get_the_terms($post->id, get_post_meta($post->ID,'metafield-taxonomy-name',TRUE) );

$terms = get_the_terms($post->id, $taxonomy );
```

- $taxonomy must be placed outside of post loop.

Thanks!